# Nuget-packages missing when installing Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition

Tags: nuget-package, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package-restore

I installed the Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition and I started my first project.

When I let Visual Studio create the project, it's seems that there are several nugetpackages and sdk's mising.

[image]

What do I need to do to have those problems resolved?

Comment: Right click on the solution and then click "Restore packages"

Comment: @Andrey I tried that but it didn't help. I keep getting the error NU1101 and CS0518